# The text of label kept getting cut off inside the grid, how can i make it show the right size and not off?

Tags: xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

The text on the label kept cutting off when I use grid type for the row.

I tried taking out of grid for the row and it works fine but I need to use grid.  I've tried changing the rows height.

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="rain Log" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,50,0,0" /> 
    <ListView x:Name="postListView" >  
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>           
        <!-- from the post.cs -->
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell >
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="lime" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions > <!-- 8 rows -->
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                      
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>                 
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  

                        <!-- rain1 Row 1 -->

                        <Grid Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="`cornflowerblue`" > 
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding rain1Lbl}"/>                
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding rain1vol}" 
HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" /> 
                        </Grid>
                        <!-- endrow1   -->  
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>            
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

I dont want the text to get cut off for the label as I'm going to add 7 more rows.

Comment: Could you please post more details about this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some structural problems in your XAML regarding the use of `ListView` and `Grid`. `ListView` automatically creates a row for every object of the source list. If you're not assigning a `ItemSource` to it, it will have no data. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview?view=xamarin-forms) on how to properly use a `ListView`.

There are also some problems with your `Grid`. If you want every row height to be `Auto`, you don't have to explicitly define them, as the default is `Auto`, and you don't have to define each row you want to add. Also, you're defining another `Grid` component inside your `Grid`, which will not work as you expect. The inside grid will, as default, occupy the first column ("0"), and the second row (as you set `Grid.Row` to "1", but the first one should be "0"), and any `Grid.Column` you add to elements inside this second `Grid` will occupy only the first column of the external `Grid`.

What you want to do will look something like this:

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="lime" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                      
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>                 
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  

    <!-- Row 0 -->
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding rain1Lbl}"/>                
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding rain1vol}" 
HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />

    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding rain2Lbl}"/>                
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding rain2vol}" 
HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />

    <!-- Keep adding rows... -->     
</Grid>
```

Thats if you need to use `Grid`. I'd recommend you to use a `ListView` when you have a List as source though, as it is dynamic and you don't have to explicitly add each row, just create one template. Read more about `ListView`'s and `Grid`'s structure before trying to use it. There is a lot of good documentation made by Microsoft and the community.

Comment: This wont work since grid does not accept bindable layout

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working ok using the Grid within the ViewCell similar to the Define Item Appearance section of this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview

However to get this working perfectly for me I had to make certain to add HasUnevenRows="True" to my ListView as shown below:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Fill" x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
Margin="10" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="True">
```

Answer (score -1):

For a row, where label is added, changing RowDefinition Height from "Auto" to "*" solved my problem.